# Align bottom in hgroup in Adobe Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have HGroup with two label like following:

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="bottom" gap="1">
    <s:Label text="12" fontSize="15"  />
    <s:Label text="14" fontSize="25"  />
</s:HGroup>
```

Both have different font size. So, second label display upper than first one. How can i make them bottom align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are already aligned at the bottom but they have a different internal offset depending on the font size so letters with a descent baseline (like "g" or "j") would still fit in.

So if you want to align your numbers you should align your text to the descent baseline:

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="bottom" gap="1">
    <s:Label text="12" fontSize="15" alignmentBaseline="descent" />
    <s:Label text="14" fontSize="25" alignmentBaseline="descent" />
</s:HGroup>
```

More about that [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/formats/ITextLayoutFormat.html#alignmentBaseline)